# Уточнение по работе функции move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, fileupload

Я хочу сделать проверку: Если файл перемещен, то сделать что-то. Подскажите какой код верный:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $dest_url);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $dest_url)) {
  сделать что-то
}
```

или достаточно выполнить функцию в if чтобы файл был перемещен:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $dest_url)) {
  сделать что-то
}
```

Comment: Достаточно в if кинуть

Comment: первый код вообще работать не будет. первая строка переместит файл, вторая уже его не найдет, и условие не выполнится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $dest_url)) {
  сделать что-то
}
```

Функция move_uploaded_file вернет true, если файл успешно перемещен